# Gridview CheckBox Checked from Outside Checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm using Parent Checkbox from outside from Gridview control i.e
`<asp:CheckBox ID="chkParent" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAll();" />`

if i checked this `chkParent` Checkbox check all Gridview `chkChild` checkboxes

if i unchecked this `chkParent` Checkbox uncheck all Gridview `chkChild` checkboxes

after checked this `chkParent` Checkbox Gridview checked all `chkChild` Checkboxes, if i uncheck atleast 1 `chkChild` checkbox in Gridview Control i want to uncheck `chkParent` Checkbox

```
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkParent" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAll();" />

        <asp:Gridview ID='gridSend' runat="server">
          <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>                     
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChild" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          ------------
          ------------
          ------------
         </Columns>
        </asp:Gridview>
```

this is my JQuery code i'm using to check and uncheck its working great, but i want to uncheck `chkParent` Checkbox if i uncheck atleast one checkbox in Gridview Control

```
function SelectAll() {
        var row = $("#gridSent tr");
        if ($("#chkParent").prop("checked") == true) {
            for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                var chkCell = row[i].cells[0];
                for (var j = 0; j < chkCell.childNodes.length; j++) {
                    if (chkCell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") {
                        chkCell.childNodes[j].checked = "true";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {            
            for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {              
                var chkCell = row[i].cells[0];
                for (var j = 0; j < chkCell.childNodes.length; j++) {                    
                    if (chkCell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") {
                        chkCell.childNodes[j].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not a complete solution but just an idea how you can come to a resolution later by yourself.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkParent" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ParentCheckedChanged" />

protected void ParentCheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // loop through child checkboxes and apply parent checkbox value
    foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        CheckBox cb = row.FindControl("chkChild") as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null) cb.Checked = chkParent.Checked;
    }
}

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkChild" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ChildCheckedChanged" />
protected void ChildCheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    CheckBox cbChild = sender as CheckBox;
    if (cbChild != null) {
         if(!cbChild.Checked){
             chkParent.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Just food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Snippet:

a few things:

1. The table in the snippet is a rendered GridView.
2. `<asp:CheckBox />` controls complicate matters by wrapping  `<input type="checkbox" .../>` in a `<span>` tag.
3. Because of this, setting `<asp:CheckBox CssClass="sri" />` places the class in that span.
4. `class="sri"` is an empty class used to simplify finding the checkbox controls we need using the jquery selectors.

```js
// jQuery Selectors
var cbxParent = "th span.sri input:checkbox";
var cbxChildren = "td span.sri input:checkbox";

// jQuery Objects
var $cbxParent = null;
var $cbxChildren = null;

// Other
var CountOfChildren = 0;


$(function() {

  $cbxParent = $(cbxParent);
  $cbxChildren = $(cbxChildren);

  CountOfChildren = $cbxChildren.length;

  ToggleCheck();
});


function ToggleCheck() {
  var CountOfCheckedChildren = 0;
  var IsParent = (event.target.id === $cbxParent[0].id);

  if (IsParent) 
  {
    // Parent was Checked, check or uncheck all children
    $cbxChildren.prop("checked", event.target.checked);
    CountOfCheckedChildren = $cbxChildren.filter(":checked").length;
  } 
  else 
  {
    CountOfCheckedChildren = $cbxChildren.filter(":checked").length;
    $cbxParent.prop("checked", (CountOfChildren === CountOfCheckedChildren));
  }

  var s = "[#:" + CountOfChildren + "] [X: " + CountOfCheckedChildren + "] [IsParent:" + IsParent + "]";
  $("caption").text(s);
}
```

```css
th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:200px">
    <caption>
      Hello Sri
    </caption>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        <span class="sri"><input id="GridView1_cbxParent" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl01$cbxParent" onclick="ToggleCheck();" /></span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">Amt</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="sri"><input id="GridView1_cbxChild_0" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl02$cbxChild" onclick="ToggleCheck();" /></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="GridView1_lblDue_0">1.25</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="sri"><input id="GridView1_cbxChild_1" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl03$cbxChild" onclick="ToggleCheck();" /></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="GridView1_lblDue_1">2.5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="sri"><input id="GridView1_cbxChild_2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl04$cbxChild" onclick="ToggleCheck();" /></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="GridView1_lblDue_2">3.5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="sri"><input id="GridView1_cbxChild_3" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl05$cbxChild" onclick="ToggleCheck();" /></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="GridView1_lblDue_3">4.5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="sri"><input id="GridView1_cbxChild_4" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl06$cbxChild" onclick="ToggleCheck();" /></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="GridView1_lblDue_4">5.5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```